# Selenium testing over multiple domains

Tags: testing, selenium, same-origin-policy

I'm pretty new at Selenium, recently I've created a bunch of tests with Selenium-IDE and I wanted to run them through a .bat script against a selenium stand alone server so I could test in IE, Firefox, etc.

When running the tests in firefox everything goes well and they pass... now Internet Explorer (8) is another story, the testsuite uses the *`localhost`* as domain to test against.

But here's the tricky part - I have a static content provider which runs on another domain than localhost where my images, css and javascript is hosted. **How can I tell Selenium Server that it's ok to use multiple domains?**

I know it is disabled because of same origin policy, however firefox runs it without problems, and showing the correct css rules and images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you would need to Selenium Webdriver (or Selenium RC (older version)) to do all that you just listed.

here is the [page](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-webdriver) which will hep you get started.

Comment: the tests are created by someone else with selenium IDE, I start the tests through a stand alone version of selenium Server on our CI machine